# Undefined method error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, irb, rubymine

The following example was showed by my professor in class and it worked perfectly fine and printed

```
def printv(g)
  puts g.call("Fred")
  puts g.call("Amber")
end

printv(method(:hello))

>>hello Fred

  hello Amber
```

but when I am trying to run it on my irb/RubyMine its showing undefined method error. I am trying the exact code what he showed in class. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the code for `printv`, you'll see that `g` will have to provide a `call` method. There are several classes in Ruby that provide a `call` method by default, amongst them procs and lambdas:

```
hello = lambda { |name| puts "Hello, #{name}" }
printv(hello) # prints: Hello, Fred and Hello, Amber
```

Here `hello` is a variable storing a lambda, so you don't need a symbol (`:hello`) to reference it.

Now let's look at the method `method`. According to the docs it "[l]ooks up the named method as a receiver in obj, returning a Method object (or raising NameError)". It's signature is "obj.method(sym) → method", meaning it takes a symbol argument and returns a [method object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Method.html). If you call `method(:hello)` now, you'll get the `NameError` mentioned in the docs, since there is currently no method named "hello". As soon as you define one, things will work though:

```
def hello(name)
  "Hello, #{name}"
end
method(:hello) #=> #<Method: Object#hello>
>> printv(method(:hello)) # works as expected
```

This also explains why the call `printv(method("hello")` that you mention in your comment on the other answer fails: `method` tries to extract a method object, but fails if there is no method by that name (a string as argument seems to work by the way, seems like `method` interns its argument just in case).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to define the method "hello" as well.

```
def printv(g)
  puts g.call("Fred")
  puts g.call("Amber")
end

def hello(s)
   "hello #{s}"
end 

printv(method(:hello))

>>hello Fred

  hello Amber
```

Comment: What if I call like this? `printv(method("hello"))` with no hello defined